# LoganSquare parsing a List of custom JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have an issue with lists of JSONObject, from the android json parser LoganSquare.
I have a POJO Object that is itself a JSONObject: `StatsCategoryValues`

Then in another JSONObject class I have a list of `StatsCategoryValues`

```
@JsonField(name="last_24months")
public List <StatsCategoryValues> twoYear;
```

I get an error while compiling, not on runtime. The error has to do with the generated class which tried to import an non existing class whose name is the package of where my JSONObjects sit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, ok so it turns out the problem was my package name itself 'JSONObjects'.
I changed it to something else and it compiled fine...